# Unity 2d support dropped in 12.10,  what now?

Tags: unity, unity-2d

So its been announced. [Ubuntu is dropping unity 2d support.](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTE2MTQ)

I wouldn't mind if it wasn't for two things that are important to me.

**1) A working system**

Unity is nice, i try to use it quite often. But it lags.

**2) Support for older hardware.**

I also have old computers. You can imagine how they would work with unity if my current laptop is slog in Ubuntu.

I guess i could use another desktop environment/ window manager , like switching to fluxbox.

Anyone have any suggestion ideas/solutions on how to proceed with Ubuntu in the future?
All insights welcome

Comment: Switching to another desktop environment like fluxbox or TWM would for me mean that I'm not using Ubuntu, but something more similar to a "testing" version of Debian and that’s not what I want.
But If llvmp pipe works as well on low end pc:s as described by @mateo-salta , then I feel more calm about the future of the fitire of Ubuntu on low ends computers.

Also as someone posted out since were on a LTS release we can skip to this release longer than our "old hardware" will work. Thanks for all the informative replies!

Comment: unfortunately it seems not to work like in kde...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to this article on [Phoronix](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTA5OTA) systems without OpenGL acceleration will still be supported using the LLVMpipe driver.

> "Those without OpenGL acceleration on the GPU for running the Unity
>   desktop with Compiz will have to deal with the LLVMpipe driver for
>   Gallium3D running on your CPU. LLVMpipe is bad for gaming, but good
>   enough for a composited desktop experience. LLVMpipe already handles
>   the GNOME Shell and with Fedora 17 the GNOME-Shell-On-LLVMpipe is the
>   software fall-back method."

Sounds cool.  We'll see how well it works in practice.

References:

- http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html

Answer (score 4):

In 12.10 Unity [will run on systems without decent OpenGL support](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/08/unity-2d-removed-from-ubuntu-12-10) by using [LLVMPipe](http://www.mesa3d.org/llvmpipe.html) (see also [this bug documenting the change](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1035261)). This will come at the cost of higher CPU usage so on older systems you may want to switch to another desktop.

Answer (score 3):

#### Quantal is going to include a Gnome-Shell spinoff by default. This will work even if your system can't run Unity.

Gnome-Shell is something like the older versions before Unity.
<sub>ref: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/uds-q-summary-bye-bye-unity-2d-hello-gnome-shell-spin</sub>

In Unity 3D, your system will act slightly restrained, or even refuse to run Unity, but it is possible to install an alternate DE. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and log in giving your username and password. Then, you may use this terminal to install a DE of your choice:

- Kubuntu desktop:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
  ```
- Lubuntu desktop:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
  ```
- Xubuntu desktop:

  ```
    sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could still install lubuntu or xubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is supported until 2017 so for older computers this will be a good option if you want to use Unity 2D instead of lighter distros / desktops.