# What happen to my ubuntu if my graphic not support Unity 3D when UPGRADE to 12.10

Tags: unity, unity-2d, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity 2d support dropped in 12.10,  what now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176634/unity-2d-support-dropped-in-12-10-what-now)

Unity 2D, the light-weight counterpart to Ubuntu’s Unity interface, has been retired from Ubuntu 12.10.

The 2D version of Unity has been used as a fallback for users whose computers lack sufficient graphical grunt to run the ’3D’ version.

So what happen if I upgrade to 12.10 ?