# I get "Failed to load session "ubuntu-2d" when using XRDP

Tags: 12.10, rdp, xrdp

Initially, when I try to log in to my ubuntu machine (version 12.10) using RDP, I would get an ubuntu desktop background, with no text, menu bars, or anything to indicate it loaded the desktop.

I went through the following instructions that claimed to fix that issue:

Edit the `.Xsession` file to add the following line:

```
gnome-session –session=ubuntu-2d
```

but it caused the following error:

> Failed to load session "ubuntu-2d

and it only allows me to log out.

So now, my question is:

How to I log in to my Ubuntu Desktop using XRDP in a foolproof fashion.  I can successfully SSH in to the command line, so do I need to install another window manager? Do I need to reset some settings?

Answer (score 19):

As of Ubuntu 12.10, the Unity 2D desktop interface ("Ubuntu 2D") no longer exists. Ordinarily, computers without adequate 3D acceleration use the llvmpipe software renderer.

- [Unity 2d support dropped in 12.10,  what now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176634/unity-2d-support-dropped-in-12-10-what-now)

Since Unity 2D used to be the easy way to xRDP into an Ubuntu system, its removal requires the use of a different technique. Fortunately, there is a solution:

- [**How to remote desktop into ubuntu 12.10 using xRDP**](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3518) (by **Griffon**)

#### Install xRDP

That page provides a circuitous way to install xRDP, but really it's [as simple as before](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=xrdp&searchon=names&suite=quantal&section=all). Install [xrdp [image: Install xrdp]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xrdp) in the Software Center. Or install from the Terminal by running:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If it is not found, make sure [the Universe repository component is enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) in your Software Sources. (If this is a [headless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_system) system, use [this command-line way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78613/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository-from-the-command-line) instead.)

#### Install a Desktop Interface Not Requiring (Real or Simulated) 3D Acceleration

Grifon's instructions recommend [GNOME Fallback](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gnome-3-fallback.html) (providing the "GNOME Classic" session type). The [gnome-session-fallback [image: Install gnome-session-fallback]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-session-fallback) package provides it.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

<sup>(It's best to run `sudo apt-get update` first if you haven't done so recently.)</sup>

Other alternatives include:

- [Xfce](http://xfce.org/) ([xubuntu-desktop [image: Install xubuntu-desktop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xubuntu-desktop) / `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`)
- [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) ([lubuntu-desktop [image: Install lubuntu-desktop]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/lubuntu-desktop) / `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`)
- [MATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_%28desktop_environment%29) (this is a bit more involved to install, see these instructions)

#### Create a `~/.xsession` File Specifying the Desired Interface for xRDP

In the home directory of the user or users who you wish to log in via xRDP, create a file called `.xsession`. You can do this with any text editor, such as Gedit. Once created, this file won't be visible in file managers except when *View > Show Hidden Files* (or similar) is enabled. In Nautilus and most other file managers, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> does this.

The quickest and easiest way to make this file is probably the Terminal--a single command will create it.

To use GNOME Fallback ("GNOME Classic (no effects)"):

```
echo gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback > ~/.xsession
```

Or, to use Xfce ("Xubuntu Session"):

```
echo xfce4-session > ~/.xsession
```

Or, to use LXDE ("Lubuntu Desktop"):

```
echo lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE > ~/.xsession
```

#### Configure the Keyboard Layout

If you want an English keyboard layout, you don't need to do anything for this step.

Otherwise, to configure xRDP to use a different keyboard layout, see the "Solving the keyboard Layouts problem in the xRDP session" section of [this post](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=2879) (the rest of that post applies just to earlier versions of Ubuntu; the post was linked to from [those instructions for 12.10](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3518)).

#### Now it should work!

**Griffon** has pointed out that, unfortunately, in GNOME Fallback, the usual way of logging out does not work (when connected via xRDP). Instead, log out by running the command:

```
gnome-session-quit --logout
```

You can open a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) for this, but you might as well just use the Run dialog (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

In other desktop environments, logging out might still work, but if it does not, you can use their approximate equivalents of the [`gnome-sesison-quit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gnome-session-quit.1.html) command:

*Xfce:* `xfce4-session-logout --logout`

*LXDE:* `lxsession-logout`

#### Acknowledgements

Much of the information here is from [that blog post](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3518) (though no text is copied).

Comment: I think installing a whole new desktop environment with all the software packages is overkill. I followed the steps, but just installed openbox. Then I put '/usr/bin/openbox-session' in my .xsession and my uncle was Robert.

Comment: I used the `echo lxsession -s Lubuntu -e LXDE > ~/.xsession` method via SSH and I'm still just getting a black screen when I login with Remote Desktop for Mac.  Any tips on what could be causing the black screen?

Comment: FYI I'm getting a blank screen as well with `gnome-fallback` :(